# How to get the row with the same ID, even if it's in another row?

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates

I wrote this code here, which basically plots coordinates on rasters. If the extracted value is greater than 4, it deletes it from the existing df by subseting it. My problem is, that if there is a value > 4, the subset works as intended, but in the next iteration the NA value gets replaced in the wrong row.

The problem is the 'sly_df$Eltelt_ido[value] = i * 16', but I have no idea how could I solve it.

dnbr_reclass_r is an array which contains the file name of the rasters.

```
for (i in 1:length(dnbr_reclass_r)){
  DNBR = raster(paste0('E:/Teruletek/Solymos/dNBR_reclass/', dnbr_reclass_r[i]))
  plot(DNBR)
  points(sly_coor)
  
  extracted_values = extract(DNBR, sly_coor)
  
  for(value in 1:length(extracted_values)){
    if(extracted_values[value] > 4){
      sly_df$Eltelt_ido[value] = i * 16
    }
  }
  sly_subset = subset(sly_df, is.na(sly_df$Eltelt_ido))
  sly_coor = data.frame(x = sly_subset$x, y = sly_subset$y)
}
```

Here is the data frame which contains the coordinates, sly_df. ( sly_coor is only the 2 column, x, y, Eltelt_ido is basically the days passed )

```
sly_df
   ID        x       y Eltelt_ido
1   1 250947.8 5126356         NA
2   2 250961.2 5126359         NA
3   3 251202.3 5125685         NA
4   4 251127.2 5125503         NA
5   5 251189.7 5125774         NA
6   6 251305.8 5126352         NA
7   7 250935.7 5126549         NA
8   8 250856.0 5126148         NA
9   9 251205.2 5126735         NA
10 10 250955.7 5126356         NA
```

I tried using ChatGPT, that gave me the idea of introducing the ID's, but the solution it gave me didn't worked.

I appreciate any help, or idea mentioned .

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I got it working. I changed perspective, so instead of subsetting the coordinates, I check with an if statemens, if the corresponding Eltelt_ido is NA. If it is, it means, that it has not already met the first if statement.

```
for (i in 1:length(dnbr_reclass_r)){
  DNBR = raster(paste0('E:/Teruletek/Solymos/dNBR_reclass/', dnbr_reclass_r[i]))
  plot(DNBR)
  points(sly_coor)
  
  extracted_values = extract(DNBR, sly_coor)
  
  
  for(value in 1:length(extracted_values)){
    if(extracted_values[value] > 4){
      if (is.na(sly_df$Eltelt_ido[value])){
      sly_df$Eltelt_ido[value] = i * 16
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one loop too many:

```
for (i in 1:length(dnbr_reclass_r)){
   DNBR = raster(paste0('E:/Teruletek/Solymos/dNBR_reclass/', dnbr_reclass_r[i]))
   extracted_values = extract(DNBR, sly_coor)
   j <- which(extracted_values > 4)
   sly_df$Eltelt_ido[j] = j * 16
}
```